# How do I return a variable size string from a function?

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, character-arrays

I need a working code for a function that will return a random string with a random length.

What I want to do would be better described by the following code.

```
char *getRandomString()
{
    char word[random-length];
    // ...instructions that will fill word with random characters.
    return word;
}
void main()
{
    char *string = getRandomString();
    printf("Random string is: %s\n", string);
}
```

For this, I am strictly forbidden to use any other include than **stdio.h**.
Edit: This project will be adapted to be compiled for a PIC Microcontroller, hence I cannot use malloc() or such stuff.
The reason why I use **stdio.h** here, is for me to be able to inspect the output using **GCC**.

Currently, this code gives this error.-
“warning: function returns address of local variable [enabled by default]”

Then, I thought this could work.-

```
char *getRandomString(char *string)
{
    char word[random-length];
    // ...instructions that will fill word with random characters.
    string = word;
    return string;
}
void main()
{
    char *string = getRandomString(string);
    printf("Random string is: %s\n", string);
}
```

But it only prints a bunch of nonsense characters.

Comment: You can't return a pointer to data on the stack if you wish for predictable results. Have the caller pass the memory target (e.g. char*, *and* size limit) or return something on the heap (allocated via `malloc`, caller must `free`).

Comment: `stdio.h` is not a library, it is a header. Are you saying including `stdlib.h` is not allowed, hence `malloc` is not an option?

Comment: Why are you strictly forbidden?  If this is homework, please add the `homework` tag.  What are your specific requirements?

Comment: `void main()` is *wrong*.  Use `int main(void)`.  Complain to the author of whatever book told you to use `void main()`.

Comment: what do you mean by `random-length` is it `random` minus `length` ? or `random_length`, ie, a single variable.

Comment: @Praetorian Should I then call it a header to include part of C’s Standard Library?

Comment: @david-thornley No, It is not homework.

Comment: @keith-thompson This code will be adapted to be compiled for a PIC Microcontroller, for which the main function returning anything makes no sense.

Comment: @phoxis Random length means a length that will be determined during runtime.

Comment: @Mario: My apologies, my comment that `void main()` is wrong applies only to hosted implementations.  For freestanding implementations, the program's entry point is implementation-defined.  (I'd still suggest writing the more explicit `void main(void)`; `main` takes no arguments, not an unspecified number and type of arguments.)

Comment: @keith-thompson You made me a little curious about the latest part of your answer. I have been coding in C for little time so I am not aware of many of that stuff. Can you please provide me some link explaining clearly why it is a good practice to declare the main function that way when it takes no arguments?

Comment: @Keith: The difference in `void main()` and `void main(void)` applies only to declarations; for the *definition* of the function, the two are identical.

Comment: @R..: The definition is also a declaration.

Comment: @Mario: It probably doesn't make much, if any, difference for main, but in general `void foo(void)` says that foo takes no arguments (so a call `foo(42)` will be diagnosed as an error), whereas `void foo()` says that it takes an unspecified number and type(s) of arguments, so `foo(42)` won't be diagnosed; it will just cause undefined behavior.  The form with the empty parentheses is an old-style pre-ANSI declaration.  (Note that the rules are different for C++; C++ doesn't support old-style declarations, so it's able to make `()` specifically mean no parameters.)

Comment: @Keith: Yes it's also a declaration, but it's not a declaration that leaves the arguments unspecified.

Comment: @R..: `void foo() { } int main(void) { foo(42); return 0; }`.  No diagnostic is required on the incorrect call (and gcc, for example, doesn't complain).  Change `()` to `(void)` and you get a required diagnostic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three common ways to do this.

1. Have the caller pass in a pointer to (the first element of) an array into which the data is to be stored, along with a length parameter.  If the string to be returned is bigger than the passed-in length, it's an error; you need to decide how to deal with it.  (You could truncate the result, or you could return a null pointer.  Either way, the caller has to be able to deal with it.)
2. Return a pointer to a newly allocated object, making it the caller's responsibility to call `free` when done.  Probably return a null pointer if `malloc()` fails (this is always a possibility, and you should *always* check for it).  Since `malloc` and `free` are declared in `<stdlib.h>` this doesn't meet your (artificial) requirements.
3. Return a pointer to (the first element of) a *static* array.  This avoids the error of returning a pointer to a locally allocated object, but it has its own drawbacks.  It means that later calls will clobber the original result, and it imposes a fixed maximum size.

None if these is an ideal solution.

Comment: @alvin: Not if you're not allowed to use `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: A variant on #2 is to define a symmetric `freeRandomString()` function which takes care of clear-up.  This may be overkill in this simple example, but is much, much cleaner when you're dealing with more complex data structures.

Comment: @Oli: Another approach I've used is to have static array of N results and a static index into the array.  Increment the index on each call, setting it back to 0 when it reaches the end.  This means the caller doesn't have to worry as much about each call clobbering the result of the previous one, but it can fail badly if you try to save more than N results.

Comment: I have used the Third Keith’s approach which worked perfectly. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It points to nonsense characters because you are returning local address. `char word[random-length];` is defined local to `char *getRandomString(char *string)`

Dynamically allocate the string with `malloc`, populate string, and return the returned address by `malloc`. This returned address is allocated from the heap and will be allocated until you do not manually free it (or the program does not terminate).

```
char *getRandomString(void)
{
    char *word;
    word = malloc (sizeof (random_length));
    // ...instructions that will fill word with random characters.
    return word;
}
```

After you have done with the allocated string, remember to free the string.

Or another thing can be done, if you cannot use `malloc` which is define the local string in the `getRandomString` as `static` which makes the statically declared array's lifetime as long as the program runs.

```
char *getRandomString(void)
{
    static char word[LENGTH];
    // ...instructions that will fill word with random characters.
    return word;
}
```

Or simply make the `char word[128];` global.

Comment: I dont think he can use malloc.

Comment: then either declare the array as static, or make it global.

Comment: I cannot use malloc.
If I declare the array as static in the function, compiler throws the error “error: storage size of ‘str’ isn’t constant”.
And I am unable to reserve too much memory since I will be compiling for a PIC microcontroller with very very little memory available.

Comment: @Mario:  There's three ways to designate storage in C:  statically, locally (on the stack), and dynamically (`malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`).  You can't do it dynamically, and you can't return local storage, so you have to do it statically.  That means you need to specify the maximum string size at compile time.

Comment: @David-Thornley thanks for your answer, it was the most clarifying one, I would have choosen your answer as the correct one if you added it as answer but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your examples are returning pointers to local variables - that's generally a no-no.  You won't be able to create memory for your caller to use without `malloc()`, which isn't defined in `stdio.h`, so I guess your only option is to make `word` static or global, unless you can declare it in `main()` and pass the pointer to your random string function to be filled in.  How are you generating random numbers with only the functions in `stdio.h`?

Comment: Actually the numbers are generated by a different mechanism that does not matter at all here, the only important thing is that after that function, the array of a determined-at-runtime length will be filled with random data.
I am using stdio only to inspect this in GCC, I will later adapt the solution to be compiled for a PIC Microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, malloc is not an option.

Write a couple of functions to a) get a random integer (strings length), and b)a random char.

Then use those to build your random string.

For example:

```
//pseudocode
static char random_string[MAX_STRING_LEN];
char *getRandomString()
{
    unsigned int r = random_number();

    for (i=0;i<r;i++){
        random_string[i] = random_char();
    }

    random_string[r-1] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to use `malloc` you'll have to declare an array that can be the maximum possible size at file scope and fill it with random characters.

```
#define MAX_RANDOM_STRING_LENGTH  1024
char RandomStringArray[MAX_RANDOM_STRING_LENGTH];

char *getRandomString(size_t length)
{
  if( length > ( MAX_RANDOM_STRING_LENGTH - 1 ) ) {
    return NULL; //or handle this condition some other way

  } else {
    // fill 'length' bytes in RandomStringArray with random characters.
    RandomStringArray[length] = '\0';
    return &RandomStringArray[0];

  }
}

int main()
{
    char *string = getRandomString(100);
    printf("Random string is: %s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be declared at file scope.  It can be declared inside the function with the `static` keyword.  And `return &RandomStringArray[0];` can be written as `return RandomStringArray;`.

Comment: @Keith Thompson Yes on both counts. About the latter, I prefer the syntax I've used over the one you've mentioned.