# Do calling conventions prevent variable size return values?

Tags: c, calling-convention, variable-length-array

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7194904/682466), when returning variable-size data from a C function, you either:

1. Pass a pointer and max length. Return a flag indicating if max is reached.
2. Return a pointer to dynamically allocated data.
3. Return a pointer to global data.

**Is there anything about calling conventions on typical hardware that prevent returning dynamic sized data via the call stack?**

Some C compilers have VLAs (or `alloca`) so variable-size data on the call stack is possible. It would seem reasonably straightforward to implement a variable-size array return value by growing the caller's stack frame as if a VLA were declared instead of the function invocation. After returning, the callee would leave the element count, followed by the elements.

Comment: If a struct is returned, the size of the struct is known, since it is declared somewhere. There is no mechanism to tell, how many elements a dynamic sized array on the stack has.

Comment: @Ctx I'm aware of that. Will try to improve the question.

Comment: You are talking about some kind of language that is not C.  What you are proposing has many sharp edges, perf is by far the biggest problem.  It has a very straight-forward solution, have the caller allocate the memory.  With a sharp edge, you need a protocol to ensure that it allocated enough.  Standard solution is the call the function *twice*.  First to determine what size is need, again to get the job done.

Comment: You can allocate stack variables in the caller using compound literals:  `asctime_s((char[26]){0}, 26, localtime_r((time_t[1]){time(NULL)}, &(struct tm){0}));`. Returning dynamic sized data prevents the C standard, which says that VLAs must have auto storage duration.

Comment: @HansPassant why is perf the biggest problem?

Comment: Because it has to be copied from temporary data that is no longer valid after the function returns.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Comment: You can return a struct that has a variable length array as the last member as illustrated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23420727/1212725

Comment: @bruceg No, that memory would be allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Before VLAs, we used the `alloca` standard library function, which does in effect return variable-size data. (It happens that the data is uninitialized but that's not essential to the implementation.) So evidently it is possible.

However, there is an important detail: `alloca` allocates storage each time it is called, and there is no `freea`. The only way to release the storage is to return from the function which calls alloca.

That's a plausible interface for local storage allocation, but not so great for a function which returns useful data. If you were to call `functionWithVariableReturnSize()` in a loop, you would end up with all the return values being saved in the stack frame until the frame is exited. That's probably not desirable, and it's probably not a good idea even if it matched some use case.

Comment: `alloca` returns a pointer to the allocated data, of course, which is #2 on the OP's list of (I take them as) *alternatives* to what he's asking about.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was referring to memory allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: @johnBollinger: alloca returns the address, but it puts the data on the stack. So it's not really #2.

Answer (score 1):

Variable-length arrays (which are an optional feature) are the only kind of dynamically-sized data structure C offers that has a source representation distinct from a pointer.  C provides no mechanism even to express passing or returning arrays *at all*, however, because array-valued expressions decay to pointers in function argument lists and `return` statements.  This is not a matter of calling convention, however, but rather deeply-rooted aspect of the language's design.

There *are*, of course, calling convention considerations that impact the implementation of function return values, but C implementations have had to work around the most significant of those already when it comes to functions returning structure types.  If C supported returning arrays, then I don't think much new would be required on the calling convention front to support returning VLAs.

Comment: You cannot return an array from a function, but nothing stops you from returning `struct { T[FIXED_SIZE]; }`. That still doesn' t let you return a VLA, but I think it shows that the ban on returning arrays is not that deeply rooted.

Comment: Indeed yes, @rici.  That's what my second paragraph is all about.